# Non-applicable Arguments, expected (String, Map<String, Object>); actual (String, Map<String, List<?>>)

Tags: java, oop, generics

I've been writing a MongoDB interface in java and recently ran into this code snag.

I have a call to insert a document:

```
insertMongoDocument(String testName, Map<String, Object> input)
```

And I have the corresponding unit test:

```
Writer.insertMongoDocument("TestName", testMap);
```

Test map is of the form

```
protected static Map<String, List<?>> testMap;
```

Why is this an illegal argument? Is a `Map<String, List<?>>` not a `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: Covariance of generic types is a nonexistent feature in Java. Yes, those are different types for Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java, the type has to match *exactly* as declared. That is given

```
insertMongoDocument(String testName, Map<String, Object> input)
```

you can't call it with

```
Map<String, List<?>> map;
insertMongoDocument("foo", map);
```

Even though it seems that `Map<String, List<?>>` should be an instance of `Map<String, Object>`, it isn't.

This is another case of generics seeming to not follow basic inheritance, ie `List<SubClass>` is **not** an instance of `List<SuperClass>`.

If it were true, it would lead to this bug:

```
List<Integer> listI = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> listN = listI; // compile error, but let's assume OK
listN.add(1.2); // Adding a Double (which is a Number) to a list of Integer - oops!
Integer i = listI.get(0); // BOOM... ClassCastException!
```

The line

```
List<Number> listN = listI;
```

is not allowed for what now should be obvious reasons, and this is basically what you're seeing: You can't cast a generic type like you would a class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following signature

```
insertMongoDocument(String testName, Map<String, ? extends Object> input)
```

The reason for this is that Java cannot relate parametric types. It tries to apply only the rules that it knows about. In your original signature it knows that it can accept `Object` for the second type parameter of `Map`, then it finds `List<?>` which is not an *exact* match so the error is returned. The `extend` and `super` operators need to be used to specify a set of applicable types instead of an exact match.

The one and only Jon Skeet has an excellent explanation on this topic: [What is a difference between <? super E> and <? extends E>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368166/what-is-a-difference-between-super-e-and-extends-e)

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up changing it to. How is this type safe though since everything extends object?
(Not that it's relevant, but an interesting thought)

Comment: Yes, but in the body of the method you can be sure that the objects returned from the Map comply at least with the Object interface. This is a very important detail.

Answer (score 0):

Because if it were legal, you could pass it to a method like insertMongoDocument which could attempt to call `input.put("", new Anything())` which would destroy type safety.

The most general type you can use for a signature here is `insertMongoDocument( String s, Map< String, ? super List< ? > > )`.