# Why is it necessary to extend in case of read and super in write in generics wildcards?

Tags: java, generics

I am having a hard time to understand the concept of generics wild cards.

As per my understanding `<?>` type unknown is introduced to resolve the co-variance not supported in generics and it should fit any type of collection and `<?extends T>` means that you can have collection of types `T` or the class which extends `T.<?super T>` means you can have collection of types `T` or super(s) of `T`.

Please correct me, if the above is wrong.

When I try to write it like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Gclass {
    static Gclass t;

    public void write(List< ?super String > lw){
        lw.add("b");
    }

    public void read(List< ? extends String> lr){
        String s=lr.get(2);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        t=new Gclass();
        List<String> l=new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("a");
        l.add("");
        System.out.println(l);
        t.write(l);
        System.out.println(l);
        t.read(l);
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

It works but my places of doubt are:

1. As per my understanding both (extends and super) includes the type declared, so in this particular case as my `List` is of type `String`. I could interchange the extends and super, but I get compilation error?
2. In case of write `? super Object` is not working? It should work as it is super of `String`?
3. I did not check for read as `String` can not be extended, but I think I'm also missing a concept here.

I've read all answers on SO related to this problem, but am still not able to have a good understanding about it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13409697/697630

Comment: I always point to [Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for an example where `? super T` makes sense. The Comparator is a consumer. You can give `sort` a Comparator that compares T or a superclass of T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per my understanding both(`extends` and `super`) includes the type declared(`String` here), so in this particular case as my `List` is of type `String`... I could interchange the `extends` and `super` but i get compilation error?

You're right that both `? extends String` and `? super String` includes `String`. But you are missing the point that, `? super String` also includes `CharSequence`, `Object`, which is not in bounds of `? extends String`. You can add a `String` to a `List<? super String>`, b'coz whatever type that list is of, it can definitely refer to a `String`. But, you cannot add say an `Integer` to a `List<? extends Number>`, because the list can be a `List<Float>` actually.

> In case of write `? super Object` is not working? It should work as it is super of `String`?

`Object` is a super class of `String` will fit in where you have `? super String`, and use `Object` for that. So, `? super String` can capture `Object`, but `? super Object` cannot capture `String`, as `String` is not a super type of `Object`. Think of it like this: "Actual type replaces the `?`, and it must satisfy the rules attached to that `?`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got the point. Still i have one doubt regarding wildcards... If i declare void write(List<?> list) and call write with a list of String, then why inside write i am not able to add a String in the list?

Comment: @user3209450 B'coz compiler doesn't really know what kind of list might be coming? What if compiler allowed adding a `String`, and you passed a `List<Integer>`?

Answer (score 5):

String is indeed a bit of a bad example as it is a `final` class, but consider something like `Number` instead.

If a method takes a parameter of type `List<? extends Number>` then you can pass it a `List<Number>` or a `List<Integer>` or a `List<BigDecimal>` etc.  Within the method body it is therefore fine to take things *out* of the list (as you know they must be instances of `Number`) but you can't put anything *in* because you don't know whether or not it's safe (the compiler can't let you risk putting an `Integer` into a `List<Float>`, for example).

Conversely if the method takes `List<? super Number>` then you can pass it a `List<Number>` or `List<Object>` - you can't take anything out of this list because you don't know what type it is<sup>*</sup>, but you do know that it'll definitely be safe to put a `Number` *in*.

<sup>* technically you can take things out but the only type you can assign them to is `Object`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`List<? super String>` means that `lw` holds a value of `List` with type argument which is `String` or it's superclass, so you can add a `String` value `"b"` (because it can be casted to list's type argument).

`List<? extends String>` means that `lw` holds a value of `List` with type argument which is `String` or it's subclasses, so values from `lw` can be casted to `String`.