# Difference in the type of "Array of Objects" AND "ArrayList of same Objects"?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, casting, type-conversion

I am unable to understand the difference in the type of "Array of Objects" AND "ArrayList of same Objects". For example I have Interface X:

```
public interface X {

    public void implemntX();
}
```

Class XYZ implementing X:

```
public class XYZ implements X{

@Override
public void implemntX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Following codes works perfect:

```
X arraryOfX[] = new XYZ[10];

if(arraryOfX instanceof XYZ[]){
        System.out.println("arraryOfX is instanceOF XYZ[]");
    }else{
        System.out.println("arraryOfX is NOT instanceOF XYZ[]");
    }

Output: arraryOfX is instanceOF XYZ[]
```

But following line of code gives me compile time error:

```
ArrayList<X> arrayListOFX = new ArrayList<XYZ>();

ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<XYZ> to ArrayList<X>
```

To the best of my understanding, ArrayList internally uses array then why Type mismatch error is bubbling up?

Comment: This [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13409697/697630) might help too since  it provides a comparison between arrays an generic collections.

Comment: BTW You have an `array or references to Objects` or an `ArrayList of references to Objects`  The same references can appear in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of XYZ is not a list of X, even if XYZ inherits from or implements X.Java  Generics do not allow that.
To be more explicit, change XYZ and X by real objects (cats and animals) like it was said in the [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: Please mark the question as a duplicate, rather than simply adding an answer sighting the link that is the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had `class ABC implements X` you CAN add an instance of ABC to `List<X>` but you CAN'T add it to `ArrayList<XYZ>`.

Just because ArrayList is backed by an array, don't confuse the 2.