# Generic bounded wildcard of function input type

Tags: java, generics, java-8

While reading the `Stream` interface source code I found this method signature:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

I wonder why the input type of `mapper` is `? super T` while the output type is `? extends R`, why not use `? extends` for both?

Comment: the difference between super and extends has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368166/what-is-a-difference-between-super-e-and-extends-e

Comment: I know the difference, but I wonder why they did that?

Comment: If you don't mind the different notation, here is an actual talk that explains it https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2014/Keynote-Duality

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a rule of thumb which was first mentionned by [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) in his [Effective Java book](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC) which stands as [**PECS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

- PE Producer extends
- CS Consumer super

This function produce a result `(? extends R)` from what it received (`? super T`).

The documentation of [`java.util.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) is kinda clear on that :

> Represents a function that accepts one argument and produces a result.

Answer (score 20):

Consider you want to map a `CharSequence` to another `CharSequence` (thus `T = R = CharSequence`). Which functions will work for you?

```
Function<Object, String> fn1 = Object::toString;
```

Is it good for you? Yes, because it can take *any* `CharSequence` (which is also `Object`) and convert it to the `String` (which is also `CharSequence`).

```
Function<CharSequence, StringBuilder> fn2 = StringBuilder::new;
```

Is it good for you? Yes, because it can take *any* `CharSequence` and convert it to the `StringBuilder` (which is also `CharSequence`).

```
Function<String, String> fn3 = String::trim;
```

Is it good for you? No, because it cannot take *any* `CharSequence`, only some of them.

Thus you can see that first type argument must be `CharSequence` or any superclass, but second must be `CharSequence` or any subclass.

Answer (score 13):

Because of [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) :) - *Producer Extends, Consumer Super*

**Producer Extends** - If you need a List to produce `T` values (you want to read Ts from the list), you need to declare it with `? extends T`

**Consumer Super** - If you need a List to consume `T` values (you want to write Ts into the list), you need to declare it with `? super T`

Comment: This answer, while saying correct facts, doesn't directly answer the question. Maybe add a sentence or two to tell how it relates to the Stream method mentioned above?