# Arraylist generics/wildcard etiquette

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm looking to understand all of the detailed reasons/motivations/uses for each of these, but there are so many combinations while it all seems the same to me, that I am confused about the nuances of what I think is called generics(wildcards, Object, T, E etc., don't know if *all* of that falls under generics)

If I have something like this I want to make an arraylist out of:

```
Media<T> //Baseclass
Book<T> //Subclass
Movie<T> //Subclass
```

Which of these would be most appropriate to make/use in this case, and why?(If necessary, let's assume I'll only use String and Integer for these Books, Movies) :

- `ArrayList<Media> = new ArrayList<Media>;`
- `ArrayList<Media<T>> = new ArrayList<Media<T>>;`
- `ArrayList<Media<?>> = new ArrayList<Media<?>>;`
- `ArrayList<? extends Media> = new ArrayList<? extends Media>;`
- `ArrayList<Object> = new ArrayList<Object>;`
- `ArrayList<> = new ArrayList<>;`
- Some other one?

And if the baseclass was abstract, would that make a difference/impact the choice?

I know that Object is the super-super class and "can assume any form", I know wildcards signal that the next object may be any kind, but so do E and T, right? I know that ? extends Media means it will be a type of Media. It all seems the same to me otherwise, I wouldn't know how to justify a specific choice.

EDIT:
Complete example below

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Something {

    public class Media<T>{
        T data;
        public T getData(){ return this.data; }
        public void setData(T data){ this.data = data; }
    }
    public class Book<T> extends Media<T>{
        T data;
        @Override
        public T getData(){ return this.data; }
        @Override
        public void setData(T data){ this.data = data; }
    }
    public class Movie<T> extends Media<T>{
        T data;
        @Override
        public T getData(){ return this.data; }
        @Override
        public void setData(T data){ this.data = data; }
    }

    ArrayList<Media> arrList;

    public Something() {
         this.arrList = new ArrayList<Media>();
         this.arrList.add(new Book<Integer>());
         this.arrList.add(new Movie<String>());

         this.arrList.get(0).setData(12);
         this.arrList.get(1).setData("Hello");

         System.out.println(this.arrList.get(0).getData()+10);
         System.out.println(this.arrList.get(1).getData()+10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Something s = new Something();
    }

}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Media<T>>` would seem the most natural choice. But it's not clear what `T` is or what your actual use case is.

Comment: Just adding various kinds to an array of baseclass, like so:
`arrList.add(new Book<String>);
arrList.add(new Movie<Integer>);`

And maybe some function from baseclass with the return-type T that each overrides.

Comment: It would help if you posted a more complete example.

Comment: Added one just now.

Comment: what does Book<String> mean? what does Movie<Integer> mean? seems to me your example doesnt need the <T> bit at all

Comment: Book<String> would mean that the object will make its member "data" a String from thereon out. Movie<Integer> means that that particular Movie-object's member var data will be an Integer from now on.
I know I don't need the T, this is just an example, I'm wondering if it makes a difference or why I should use a certain combination in this ordinary, low-level case, why not the others.

Comment: Like, what happens if I use ArrayList<? extends Media> instead? I don't see any difference nor reason to use it, so why would I ever use it? Surely they made all of these combinations for some advantage or detail that each of them solves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368166/what-is-a-difference-between-super-e-and-extends-e) on the effects of using "super" or "extends" in generic type specifications. The short version is that `Collection<? extends T>` is read-only while `Collection<? super T>` is append-only.

For this reason I personally prefer to completely avoid both these qualifiers since they are generally more restrictive than a simple `Collection<T>`.

However, they are sometimes useful when designing APIs for purposes of contra and counter variance (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501023/demonstrate-covariance-and-contravariance-in-java))

`Collection<?>` I only use when dealing with legacy code (that doesnt use generics) to avoid a compiler warning. Its effectively the same as `Collection<Object>`, but to me is clearer. I try never to write new code that requires `<?>`