# Why cannot write in covariance in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have code like this:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();

        List<? extends Animal> animals = cats;

        animals.add(new Cat()); // compile error

        Animal animal = animals.get(0);
    }
}

class Animal {

}

class Cat extends Animal {

}

class Dog extends Animal {

}
```

Why cannot add a Cat instance to animals? Add Cat instance or Dog instance to animals, and read elements as animal is type safe. I know PECS (short for "Producer extends and Consumer super"), but I can't understand that why can't write in covariance and cant't read in contravariance in Java.

Comment: PECS. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2970947

Comment: You may want to [read this first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13409697/697630).

Comment: What if instead of `new Cat()`, you had added a `new Dog()` to animals? What would `Cat c = cats.get(0)` do?

Answer (score 0):

`<? extends Animal>` is not `Cat`, it can be any subclass ot `Animal`, for example:

```
List<? extends Animal> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
dogs.add(new Cat()); // compile error
```

No matter what actually type `<? extends Aminal>` is, it can't add any subclass of `Animal`. Use `List<Animal>` instead of `List<? extends Animal>`.