# Difference between List<? super T> and List<Class<? super T>

Tags: java

I was going through generics in Java and I'm having trouble trying to understand where I would use the following two.

I understand that the first `myList` would ensure that the list only contains elements of type `Integer` and all it's superclasses. Now I'm trying to figure out where `myList2` would fit in here.

```
List<? super Integer> myList;
List<Class<? super Integer>> myList2;
```

Edit: It's not a duplicate of the question being linked...since this is clearly regarding the use of `?` vs `Class<?` whereas the other question is about `super` vs `extend`

Comment: `myList2.add(Integer.class);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a difference between <? super E> and <? extends E>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368166/what-is-a-difference-between-super-e-and-extends-e)

Comment: `myList` is a list of **object instances**, e.g. a `List<Number>` storing `Integer`, `Double`, `BigDecimal`, ... objects, such as `42`, `3.14159`, `3e9876`, ... --- `myList2` is a list of **`Class` objects**, i.e. a list of `Integer.class`, `Number.class`, `Object.class`, `Serializable.class`, or `Comparable.class` values.

Comment: I understand the difference between super and extends. I was just wondering where myList2 would be used.

Comment: To be exact, the second one contains objects whose type is Class\<Integer\>, not classes of type Integer. 'Class' is a generic class, objects of that class are objects, not classes.

Comment: I can't offhand think of a use for a list of class objects, but in general you use a Class object as a way to indicate type, or as a way to determine the properties of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one, 'myList' may contain integer values. Example: `myList.add(200);`

The second one, 'myList2' may contain classes of type integer. Example: `myList2.add(Integer.class);`

**Update:**
As correctly pointed out in the comments, due to the "super" keyword being applied, in *addition* to objects/ classes of type Integer, all *superclasses* of the type Integer (that is: Number and Object) can be contained as well.

Comment: Ok so like you mentioned in the comments, if instead of Integer, I'm extending Number, then the second list could contain elements Integer, BigDecimal etc.

Comment: The first list might also contain e.g. `String` values, because it might be a `List<Object>`. --- The second list can also store classes of other types, e.g. `Number.class`, `Object.class`, `Serializable.class`, and `Comparable.class`.

Answer (score 0):

The first list contains **objects** of Integer and its superclasses.
The second one contains **class objects** (or simply classes) of Integer and its superclasses, i.e:

```
Integer.class;
Number.class;
```

You can read more about the differences here: [The difference between Classes, Objects, and Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances)