# What does the generic nature of the class Class<T> mean? What is T?

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection

I understand generics when it comes to collections. But what does it mean in the case of the `Class<T>` class? When you instantiate a `Class` object, there's only one object. So why the `T` parameter? What is it specifying? And why is it necessary (if it is)?

Comment: _[Tim, use the Source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Class.java.html)_

Comment: This answer is a suitable one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19545123/3378204

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Type parameter `<T>` has been added to `java.lang.Class` to enable one specific idiom<sup>1</sup> - use of `Class` objects as type-safe object factories. Essentially, the addition of `<T>` lets you instantiate classes in a type-safe manner, like this:

```
T instance = myClass.newInstance();
```

Type parameter `<T>` represents the class itself, enabling you to avoid unpleasant effects of type erasure by storing `Class<T>` in a generic class or passing it in as a parameter to a generic method. Note that `T` by itself would not be sufficient to complete this task<sup>2</sup>: the type of `T` is erased, so it becomes `java.lang.Object` under the hood.

Here is a classic example where `<T>` parameter of the class becomes important. In the example below, Java compiler is able to ensure type safety, letting you produce a typed collection from a SQL string and an instance of `Class<T>`. Note that the class is used as a *factory*, and that its type safety can be verified at compile time:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> select(Class<T> c, String sqlStatement) {
    Collection<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    /* run sql query using jdbc */
    for ( /* iterate over jdbc results */ ) {
        T item = c.newInstance();
        /* use reﬂection and set all of item’s ﬁelds from sql results */
        result.add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since Java erases the type parameter, making it a `java.lang.Object` or a class specified as the generic's [upper bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification), it is important to have access to the `Class<T>` object inside the `select` method. Since `newInstance` returns an object of type `<T>`, the compiler can perform type checking, eliminating a cast.

---

<sup>1</sup> <strike>SUN</strike> Oracle has published [a good article explaining all this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).
<sup>2</sup> This is different from implementations of generics without type erasure, such as one in .NET.
<sup>3</sup> [Java Generics tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/generics-tutorial-159168.pdf) by Oracle.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I'm sorry but I don't quite get it. Could you perhaps give me an example of how and why you would do that?

Comment: Without that, the `instance` would be of class `Object`, and you'd need to typecast to make it useful.

Comment: is type erasure just a hack to support something that wasn't designed into the language from the start? or does it have some real benefits over non-type erasure generics (sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm not really familiar with C# style generics)

Comment: @ycomp Type erasure is a technique of keeping generics implementation entirely within the compile phase, without "spilling" into JVM. C#'s approach, on the other hand, splits the implementation of generics across the compiler and CLR (C#'s counterpart of JVM).

Answer (score 8):

The [answer by dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406049/1468366) already demonstrated one of the main uses of this parameter. There is one more aspect I consider relevant: using that parameter, you can restrict the kind of class you want to pass at a given location. So e.g.

```
Class<? extends Number> cls
```

means that `cls` may be any class implementing the `Number` interface. This can help catching certain errors at compile time, and makes class argument requirements more explicit.

Perhaps a comparison to the case without generics is in order

```
// Java ≥5 with generics    // Java <5 style without generics
Class<? extends Foo> c;     Class c;
Foo t1 = c.newInstance();   Foo t1 = (Foo)c.newInstance();
Object obj;                 Object obj;
Foo t2 = c.cast(obj);       Foo t2 = (Foo)c.cast(obj);
```

As you can see, not having `T` as an argument would require a number of explicit casts, as the corresponding methods would have to return `Object` instead of `T`. If `Foo` itself is a generic type argument, then all those casts would be unchecked, resulting in a sequence of compiler warnings. You can suppress them, but the core issue remains: the compiler cannot check the validity of these casts unless you properly use the type argument.

Comment: @Redandwhite, I'd be happy if you could express this “+1” sentiment by a click to the nice little upwards arrow next to my question, thank you very much. :-D

Comment: By the way, how common is Java Reflection in real life? It's the only part of generics that I'm not understanding. In almost a year of professional Java development, I haven't yet found a need for Reflection, although I use generics in Collections all the time

Comment: @Redandwhite, reflection is used by quite a number of frameworks, for taks like serialization (e.g. jaxb), dependency injection (e.g. guice), method enumeration (e.g. junit) and so on. So as an application developer, not using them is normal. As a library developer, it depends on the library. Note that you also need properly typed `Class` arguments for runtime type-checked containers like [`Collections.checkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Class%29) and friends provide them.

Answer (score 3):

In Java there's a single metaclass: `Class`. Its instances (only one per type exists) are used to represent classes and interfaces, therefore the `T` in `Class<T>` refers to the *type* of the class or interface that the current instance of `Class` represents.

Comment: Your argumentation doesn't seem very conclusive to me. All you say is correct, except for the “therefore”. You could very easily have a single meta class with instances representing types, without having that class be a generic. It worked that way before generics arrived.

Answer (score 0):

The use of generics in the Class type is top define the type of class. If I have ' Class  obj' my object obj can holds only children of Charsequence.
This is an optional argument. I'm often put an '?' to avoid warnings from the Eclipse IDE if I don't need an specific type of class.