# How to interpret "public <T> T readObjectData(... Class<T> type)" in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have this Java code.

```
public <T> T readObjectData(ByteBuffer buffer, Class<T> type) {
...
T retVal = (T) summaries;
return retVal;
```

How to interpret this code? Why do we need `public <T> T` instead of `public T`?

How to give the parameter to the 2nd argument (`Class<T> type`)?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This declares the `readObjectData` method generic, with one type parameter, `T`.

```
public <T> ...
```

Then the return type is `T`.

```
... T readObjectData(...
```

Without the initial `<T>`, which is the generic type declaration, the symbol `T` will be undefined.

In the parameter list, `Class<T> type` is one of the parameters.  Because the return type and this parameter both reference `T`, this ensures that if you pass in a `Class<String>`, then it will return a `String`.  If you pass in a `Class<Double>`, then it will return a `Double`.

To pass in the parameter, pass in any `Class` object, e.g. `String.class`.

Answer (score 35):

The `<T>` part is declaring a *generic type argument* `T`.  If you were to omit this part, the compiler would likely complain that the type `T` doesn't exist.

In this case, `T` serves as a placeholder for an actual type, which will only be determined when the method is actually called with non-generic type arguments.

```
public <T> T readObjectData(...
        ^  ^
        |  + Return type
        + Generic type argument
```

Answer (score 21):

`<T>` is a parameter class. There is no class named `T`. You can use this method with any class specified via second method argument named `type`.

since method is defined as following:

`public <T> T readObjectData(ByteBuffer buffer, Class<T> type)`

You can call it as written below:

`MyClass obj = o.readObjectData(buffer, MyClass.class);`

Please pay attention that you do not have to cast return value of `readOjectData()` to `MyClass`. Once upon a time, before java 5 this method would be defined as:

`public Object readObjectData(ByteBuffer)`

and its usage looked like:

`MyClass obj = (MyClass)o.readObjectData(buffer);`

Since casting may cause `ClassCastException` this is a bad practice. This was a reason for invention of generics.

Answer (score 14):

You are probably confused by a similar and more common declaration:

```
class MyClass<T> {
   private  T myMethod(T a){
       return  a;
   }
}
```

In above case, there is no need for `"<T>"` after private ( `private <T> T myMethod(T a)` )

because the `T` it's using is the same than the one defined in the class `MyClass<T>`

Even more, if you write

```
class MyClass<T> {
   private <T> T myMethod(T a){
       return  a;
   }
}
```

then the meaning is that the myMethod return type is (potentially) different than the MyClass type. As if you wrote this instead:

```
class MyClass<T1> {
   private <T2> T2 myMethod(T2 a){
       return  a;
   }
}
```

Credits: Took the example from "Kanagavelu Sugumar"'s longer answer to [How to use Class<T> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462297/how-to-use-classt-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern used by [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/) and it lets you use semantics such as:

```
String author        = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[0].author");
List<String> authors = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[*].author");
```

It's the closest thing to duck typing used in dynamic programming languages such as Javascript, which can currently be done with Java.