# What is a purpose and what is a T in HttpCallback<T>?

Tags: android

I am using one android project as a reference for my understanding,There i find this interface as:

```
    public interface HttpCallback<T> {
    void onSuccess(T var1);

    void onHttpError(ResponseStatus var1);
}
```

I got reference to this interface in `Main Activity` which implements `HttpCallback<UserDetails>`.

My question is,am not able get what is T? Please suggest me what is `T` stands for in `HttpCallback<T>`.

//Main Activity Code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends HttpCallback<UserDetails> {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        }

        HttpCallback<UserDetails> userDetailCallback = new HttpCallback<UserDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UserDetails userDetails) {
            setProgressVisibility(R.id.button_find_user, View.INVISIBLE);

               if(!"ok".equals(addressDetails.errorMsg)){
                showErrorMessage("UserDetails Error", userDetails.errorMsg);
                return;
            }
       }

        @Override
        public void onHttpError(ResponseStatus responseStatus) {
            setProgressVisibility(R.id.button_find_user, View.INVISIBLE);
            showErrorMessage("Internet Connection Problem", "Please check your Internet connection then try again.");
        }
    };
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read up on Java Generics:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888551/how-to-interpret-public-t-t-readobjectdata-classt-type-in-java

Comment: Read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: Thank you @RafiduzzamanSonnet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Generics in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java)

Comment: @2Dee I dont know about that question.I thought HttpCallback uses some kind of data i.e T. So i come up the question.

Answer (score 1):

T is nothing but a Type....Its Generics..saying that it can accept any object of that Type...Read Generics in java for more details

Comment: That really helps.Thank you