# What is the meaning of Generic <> before the return type Class<>

Tags: java, generics

I have seen few examples like below where return type contains generics twice,

what is the meaning of first set  , i understand the method should return a class of array containing elements of type C , but what is first C

```
     public static <C> Class<C[]> arrayClass(Class<C> klass) {
        return (Class<C[]>) Array.newInstance(klass, 0).getClass();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interpret "public <T> T readObjectData(... Class<T> type)" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888551/how-to-interpret-public-t-t-readobjectdata-classt-type-in-java)

Comment: `<C>` before the result type is the generic parameter declaration, and `Class<C[]>` is the concrete result type, which could also have been String or int.

Answer (score 1):

That's the declaration of a generic parameter, in your case it's named `C` but it can almost *literally* be anything. (There are constraints, like reserved keywords and general java-naming restrictions).

It is used to tell java that in the context of your method, `C` is a generic type.

Without it java would try to resolve `C` and check if a `class`, `interface` etc. would exist.

See this example:

```
public static <String> Class<String[]> arrayClass(Class<String> klass) {
    return (Class<String[]>) Array.newInstance(klass, 0).getClass();
}
```

You see that I've declared the generic parameter name to be `String`, but I don't mean `java.lang.String` that's just a placeholder name defined by me. So it works fine when I do this:

```
Class<Integer[]> klass = arrayClass(Integer.class);
```

But when I remove the `<String>` from the method, then it will fail, because java now assumes that you meant `java.lang.String`:

```
// compile error: 
//    Required type Class<String> 
//    provided      Class<Integer>
Class<Integer[]> klass = arrayClass(Integer.class);
```