# How to implement a generic method in java

Tags: java, generics

I need to override this method:

```
   @Override
   public <T> T convertValue(Object object, Class<T> clazz)
```

problem is I dont know why. I dont understand what is `<T>`. I try to rewrite it and replace T with String class:

```
   public <String> String convertValue(Object object, Class<String> clazz){
        return "a";
    }
```

but this give me error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to String
```

so now I am really confused. Can someone explain me this and show some example how to return some value ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462297/how-to-use-classt-in-java/19545123#19545123

Comment: Have you tried removing <T> like public T convertValue(Object object, Class<T> clazz) ?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I cant remove <T> because I am overring method. If I remove it then it is no override

Comment: Is your super class has this <T> in its signature ..?

Comment: nope there is just this method

Comment: add following casting 'return (String)"a"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public <T> T convertValue(Object object, Class<T> clazz)
```

is a generic method. It accepts any object, and a Class instance clazz, and it's supposed to return an instance of the given class.

So, you can call it like this:

```
String s = foo.<String>convertValue(someObject, String.class);
```

or simply

```
String s = foo.convertValue(someObject, String.class);
```

thanks to type inference.

If you have to override it, then your method implementation must comply with the contract of the base method. You can only return a String if the clazz argument is `String.class`. An implementation that returns "a" always and throws an exception if the clazz is not String.class would be, for example:

```
@Override
public <T> T convertValue(Object object, Class<T> clazz) {
    if (clazz == String.class) {
        return (T) "a";
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("I only support String, sorry");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`T` is a type parameter. It's a "placeholder" for a type.

The error you're getting is because you're shadowing ("hiding") the `String` **type** with your `String` **type parameter**. You need to remove the type parameter for the types to resolve correctly.

Also, note that even then you'll not be able to override the method since this

```
    @Override
    public String convertValue(Object object, Class<String> clazz){
            return "a";
    }
```

has an incompatible type signature with `A.convertValue()`.

This is because, in simple terms, Java requires that you should be able to use the overriding implementation of `B.convertValue()` wherever you can use `A.convertValue()` without compile errors. So you should preserve the type parameter, as JB Nizet correctly suggests.

Finally, there's a strong suspicion you might not understand what the method `convertValue` is about. Again, read JB Nizet's answer, as he provides an intuitive explanation, and be sure to read up on basic [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 0):

The rule for overriding  *`The return type should be the same or a subtype of the return type declared in the original overridden method in the superclass`*.

So it is not possible to override generic method with non generic method in the sub class unless if you specifically declare type of T when you extends like below

```
class A <T> {
    public T method(T a){
        return a;
    }
}

class B extends A<String> {

    @Override
    public String tell(String a){
        return a;
    }
}
```

But this wont work for super class like below; where T is locally defined within the method level; and sub class don't have control over it. And Subclass will fail following the overriding rule.

```
class A  {
    public <T> T method(T a){
        return a;
    }
}
```

Also read [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)