# what is the use of syntax Class<?> something

Tags: java

what is the use of syntax "`Class<?>`" ? 
how it is better than "Class something" ?

tried to find out the solution on google but didn't find any good explanation.

Comment: [Click me](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: at very first sight I though you are taking about generic but am not 100% sure, can you please explain more.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder OP aking for this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462297/how-to-use-classt-in-java

Comment: ummm... thanks Suresh