# Explanation about Class<?>

Tags: java, class, project

I working on a java Project,

My teacher sent me an example of a code and I saw something I don't know,

But his explanation wasn't the best.

Can someone explain to me more about `Class`?

***When to use and why to use***

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462297/how-to-use-classt-in-java

Answer (score 3):

`Class<?>` means any class type. 
For example, `Integer.class` is a type of `Class<Integer>`, `Double.class` is a type of `Class<Double>`.

If a type of variable is `Class<?>`, then the variable can be set to any class type.

```
Class<Integer> clazz = Integer.class (0)
Class<Integer> clazz = Double.class (x)
Class<?> clazz = Integer.class (0)
Class<?> clazz = Double.class (0)
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the usage of `class<>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class<?>[]

getClasses()
```

Returns an array containing Class objects representing all the public classes and interfaces that are members of the class represented by this Class object.

From Oracle Documantation :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html