# What does protected <T> T function() means?

Tags: java, generics

While looking into some code I found out that there is following kind of syntax.

```
 protected <T> T Execute(Class<T> returnType){
    T t;
    return t;
    }
```

What does this mean?? What if I want to save the outcome in some variable of other class?

Comment: You want to know what are Generic types in java?

Comment: than you provide the generic as the correct type, the one your variable wants to have aswell, and call it?

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: Kinda broad and not really specific question.

Comment: @Beri, I want to save variables.. That's ultimate goal

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type parameter  has been added to `java.lang.Class` to enable one specific use of Class objects as type-safe object factories. Essentially, the addition of  lets you instantiate classes in a type-safe manner, like this:

```
T instance = myClass.newInstance();
```

[How to use Class<T> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462297/how-to-use-classt-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`newInstance()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html).

```
protected <T> T execute(Class<T> returnType) {
    T t = returnType.newInstance();
    return t;
    }
```

But you will have to handle

```
InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
```

Although this is a strange, unwanted way to create new objects, AbstractFactory would be a better solution.