# What is the difference between c++0x concepts and c# constraints?

Tags: c#, c++, constraints, semantics, c++-concepts

C++0x introduces **concepts**, that let you define, basically, a type of a type. [It specifies the properties required of a type](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/cpp0xP.html).

C# let you specify **constraints** of a generic with the "*[where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8(VS.80).aspx)*" clause.

Is there any semantic difference between them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that C++ templates and C# generics are not exactly the same. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/differences-in-generics/31929#31929) for more details on those differences.

From the page you linked to explaining C++0x concepts, it sounds like the idea is that in C++ you want to be able to specify that the template type implements certain properties. In C#, the constraint goes further than that and forces the generic type to be "of" that constraint. For example, the following C# code:

```
public GenericList<T> where T : IDisposable
```

says that any type used in place of T **must** implement the IDisposable interface. Likewise, the following code:

```
public abstract class ABC {}
public class XYZ : ABC {}

public GenericList<T> where T : ABC
```

says that any type used in place of T must be of type ABC or derived from ABC.

The C++0x concept idea says only that the type used in place of T must have the same properties as defined by ABC (or IDisposable) not that it must be of that type.

Comment: if it flies like a duck and quacks like a duck then it must be a duck? :-)

Comment: Unless it's a *concept* of a duck. There does seem to be a subtle difference in that C# enforces the fact that the type must be of the constraint while a concept simply says it must have those properties but doesn't have to be of that type.