# Get JSON contract for generic type

Tags: c#, json, generics, json.net

I've got an uninstantiated generic type, e.g.

```
public class Dto<T> {
    public T t; 
}
```

I need to get a JsonContract for this type from DefaultContractResolver. When calling ResolveContract, I've got an ArgumentException - the contract resolver is trying to create a default constructor for this type, which I suspect is illegal for an uninstantiated generic type.

How can I get the contract for this type?

Comment: 1) Can you please include a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how you are calling `ResolveContract()` when it throws an exception?  2) What do you mean by *uninstantiated generic type*?  Do you mean an [open generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735035/generics-open-and-closed-constructed-types)?

Comment: Yes, that is an open generic type. I'll see if I can throw up an ideone or something.

Comment: You cannot get a contract for an open generic type.  It cannot be serialized or instantiated.  Instead each closed type will have its own contract.  But I feel this might be an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is not a type. It's just a template. To get a real type out of it you need to know the specific T.

Comment: I don't want a real type out of it. Nor do I want to serialize or instantiate it. I want a contract describing the template.

Comment: @AZ - There are no templates in c#, only generics.  And there is a type `typeof(Dto<>)`.  If I do `var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(typeof(Dto<>))` if will throw an exception.

Comment: @Puppy - c# doesn't really have templates, it has generics.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740969/c-sharp-generics-vs-c-templates-need-a-clarification-about-constraints.  So I cannot really think what "a contract describing the template" means in this context.  If you just want the property names get a contract for `Dto<int>` and go from there.

Comment: I need their types as well. If I instantiate the DTO with random types, I can't tell teh difference between a real type and the substitute type. I'd also need to somehow make substitute types that match the constraints given on the DTO type, for example.

Comment: @dbc - semantics. i meant template in the casual sense not specific to C# terminology. And if you're trying to say that it is indeed a type - well yes, but if we go this route not all types are equal :) and that's what i was trying to describe with my comment

Comment: Sure you can. The .NET type system has generic parameter proxy types that stand in for generic parameters; and the generic properties have those types. This is what I used prior to using the JsonContract mechanism.

Comment: @Puppy - well you're right - `typeof(Dto<>).GetFields()[0].FieldType` actually returns something.  But it's not something instantiable or serializable, so something like [`JsonProperty.DefaultValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) has no meaning for it.  Anyway, since an open generic type cannot be instantiated, it appears `DefaultContractResolver` has no way to give a contract for it.  It could certainly fail more gracefully though rather than throwing an exception trying to generate the constructor.

Comment: It could simply give back a contract describing the properties and then throw if you try to perform some of the operations that you can't perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dynamically generating a class to stand in for the generic arguments, instantiated it with that, and got the contract for the result. Then when I inspect the contract, I see the placeholder and I know to interpret that myself as referring to the generic parameter.