# C# generics compared to C++ templates

Tags: c#, c++, generics, templates, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between Generics in C# and Java… and Templates in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-and-java-and-templates-in-c)

What are the differences between C# generics compared to C++ templates? I understand that they do not solve exactly the same problem, so what are the pros and cons of both?

Comment: What a coincidence, that is my blog topic for today.
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx

Comment: this has *got* to be exact duplicate.
@Eric Lippert: Ooh, interesting, will give it a read

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can consider C++ templates to be an interpreted, functional programming language disguised as a generics system. If this doesn't scare you, it should :)

C# generics are very restricted; you can parameterize a class on a type or types, and use those types in methods. So, to take an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx), you could do:

```
public class Stack<T>
{
   T[] m_Items; 
   public void Push(T item)
   {...}
   public T Pop()
   {...}
}
```

And now you can declare a `Stack<int>` or `Stack<SomeObject>` and it'll store objects of that type, safely (ie, no worried about putting `SomeOtherObject` in by mistake).

Internally, the .NET runtime will specialize it into variants for fundamental types like int, and a variant for object types. This allows the representation for `Stack<byte>` to be much smaller than that of `Stack<SomeObject>`, for example.

C++ templates allow a similar use:

```
template<typename T>
class Stack
{
    T *m_Items;
    public void Push(const T &item)
    {...}
    public T Pop()
    {...}
};
```

This looks similar at first glance, but there are a few important differences. First, instead of one variant for each fundamental type and one for all object types, there is one variant for *each type it's instantiated against*. That can be a lot of types!

The next major difference is (on most C++ compilers) it will be compiled in each translation unit it's used in. That can slow down compiles a lot.

Another interesting attribute to C++'s templates is they can by applied to things other than classes - and when they are, their arguments can be automatically detected. For example:

```
template<typename T>
T min(const T &a, const T &b) {
  return a > b ? b : a;
}
```

The type T will be automatically determined by the context the function is used in.

These attributes can be used to good ends, at the expense of your sanity. Because a C++ template is recompiled for each type it's used against, and the implementation of a template is always available to the compiler, C++ can do very aggressive inlining on templates. Add to that the automatic detection of template values in functions, and you can make [anonymous pseudo-functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/lambda.html) in C++, using [boost::lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/lambda.html). Thus, an expression like:

_1 + _2 + _3

Produces an object with a *seriously scary* type, which has an operator() which adds up its arguments.

There are plenty of other dark corners of the C++ template system - it's an extremely powerful tool, but can be painful to think about, and sometimes hard to use - particularly when it gives you a twenty-page long error message. The C# system is much simpler - less powerful, but easier to understand and harder to abuse.

Comment: *Another interesting attribute to C++'s templates is they can by applied to things other than classes* - is this the same thing as C# allows us to define generics in functions (e.g. `T SomeFunc<T>(T input){...}`) ?

Comment: C++ Templates will execute faster because they are compiled in C++ to machine code (and maybe because they are compiler macros, instead of being overly generic). But C# objects don't have to be re-compiled can be placed into a dll. If you are developing a program that allows for dynamic code execution, it is possible to use a C# Generics object or function that is plugged in at runtime, with no recompile needed. I believe that this trick would be harder to pull off in C++, since its templated functions or things have to be compiled to get different instances of them.

Answer (score 5):

http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88913.aspx

Roughly, much of the difference has to do with the fact that templates are resolved at compile-time, and generics are resolved at runtime.

Comment: Actually although generics can be instantiated at runtime (through reflection, just like anything else), a lot is figured out at compile time. For example, the JIT produces a specific implementation of `List<int>` rather than using a common type-erased version equivalent to `List<object>` (this is one way it differs from Java).

Comment: @Earwicker: tell me about it.  That's why you can't do generic promotion (i.e. concatenating a List<int> to a List<object>).  The functionality exists in the CLI, but they chose not to implement it that way in C# (a mistake, IMO).

Answer (score 2):

Extensive answer on Stack Overflow: [What are the differences between Generics in C# and Java... and Templates in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/differences-in-generics)

Comment: Looks like this question is a duplicate. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog entry from Eric Gunnerson](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88913.aspx) covers this topic quite well.

The biggest immediate difference is that templates are a compile time feature whereas generics are a runtime feature.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a handy reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx