# As a skilled c# programmer what traps are waiting for me in the Java type arguments inference rules?

Tags: c#, java, generics, type-inference

Or in other words

> What are the main difference in **type arguments inference** for generic types
>   between C# and Java?

I am looking for an answer that can be read and understood in a few minutes by a skilled C# developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between Java & C# generics is that Java generics are enforced by the compiler, with the required cast being inserted as appropriate. The bytecode does not make reference to the generic type, this is termed '[type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure)'.

Within C# generics is present in the intermediate language, hence there is no erasure. As a result you can use reflection to read generic type parameters.

See this related question:

[What are the differences between Generics in C# and Java... and Templates in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-and-java-and-templates-in-c)

Comment: You can use reflection to get some generic types in Java as well despite type erasure.

Comment: @Peter: Ah yeah? How? ...generics information are not present in the bytecode anymore!

Comment: @arnaud, The generics are not used at runtime to avoid braking backward compatibility however, it is in the byte code so the compiler can get generics information for compiling code which uses a compiled `.class`. See methods like http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces%28%29 and http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes%28%29

Comment: @Peter: hi. I find your information misleading. Reading your comment, people will tend to think that you can infer an object's generic type by introspection. This is definitely not the case. The methods you are referring to will return something like `java.util.List<E>` as type, but not what `E` actually is. This remains unknown. Of course, if you use `class MyList implements List<String>` then you will obtain `java.util.List<String>` because it is fixed in that case, therefore a bit pointless. In either case, at runtime, you have no information whatsoever what generic type an object has.

Comment: @arnaud, The comment was to qualify the posters original comment that you cannot get generic information at runtime.  The use of the word "some" deserves some clarification as you have done.  There are work arounds to retain type information in Java though the language does support it.  Java 7 is supposed to give more support generic type support at runtime and is expected to be released this year.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I found people most confused by: If a type parameter only appears in the return type, the compiler has problem infer it.

```
<T> T foo();

foo(); // fail, no idea what T is
```

That example is understandable, but the following is not

```
void bar(String s){..}

bar( foo() ); // fail, compiler can't infer T=String
```

People are quite upset that the compiler can't infer a simple case like that.

Only in 2 contexts (both "assignment conversion"), Java can infer T

```
String s = foo(); // ok, T=String

String doo()
{
    return foo(); // ok, T=String
}
```

(While it compiles, it's very dangerous. How the hell does `foo()` know it should return a `String`? Due to type erasure it has no access to `T` at runtime. Java would be better off if it didn't allow inference even in these two cases.)

Of course, when inference fail, you can always provide explicity type parameter.

Comment: The implementation of foo() will be required by the compiler to return type T. Off the top of my head the only possible implementation is "return null". Therefore I'd classify it as more "useless" than dangerous although Collections.emptyList() is a close real-world analog.