# Polymorphism, overloads and generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, overloading

```
class Poly
    {
    public static void WriteVal(int i) { System.Console.Write("{0}\n", i); }
    public static void WriteVal(string s) { System.Console.Write("{0}\n", s); }
    }

class GenWriter<T>
    {
        public static void Write(T x) { Poly.WriteVal(x); }
    }
```

Why the innocent (for C++ programmer) method Write is not acceptable in C#?

You can see that the compiler tries to match the parameter type T to concrete overloads **before** instantiation:

*Error    3   The best overloaded method match for 'TestGenericPolyMorph.Poly.WriteVal(int)' has some invalid arguments*

Of course. the purpose was not to use the static method as above, the intention is to create a wrapper with polymorphic behavior.
Note: I use VS 2010.

Please, note that all the needed information is available in compile time. Once again: the problem is that the validation is performed before the template instantiation.

**Addition after the discussion:**

Well, may be I have not stressed this out properly.
The question was not only about the difference between generics and templates, but also about solution of the following problem: given set of overloads addressing different types, I want to generate set of wrapper classes providing virtual method (polymorphism) for these types.
The price of resolution of virtual methods in run-time is minimal and does not hit performance. This is where C++ templates were handy.  Obviously, the overhead of the run-time type resolution for **dynamic** is quite different.
So, the question is whether one can convert existing overloads to polymorphism without replication of the code and without paying the performance penalty (e.g., I am not sure what I gain with **dynamic** compared  to "switch" attempting to cast except of nicer syntax).

One of the solutions I have seen so far was to generate/emit code (sic!), i.e. instead of cut-and-paste to do this automatically.

So, instead of the C++ template processing we simply do it manually or just re-invent macro/template processor.

Anything better?

Comment: "The problem is that the validation is performed before the template instantiation." - Yes, that is true. You can't do that in C# because the compiler doesn't know what is the type of x in compile time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between Generics in C# and Java... and Templates in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i)

Answer (score 27):

Short answer:

C# generics are not C++ templates; despite their similar syntax they are quite different. Templates are built at compile time, once per instantiation, and the templatized code must be correct for *only the template arguments actually provided*. Templates do tasks like overload resolution and type analysis once per instantiation; they are basically a smart "search and replace" mechanism on *source code text*.

C# generics are truly generic types; they must be correct for *any possible type argument*. The generic code is analyzed *once*, overload resolution is done *once*, and so on.

Long answer: This is a duplicate of

[What are the differences between Generics in C# and Java... and Templates in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i)

See the long answers there for details.

See also my article on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Why can't you simply write:

```
public static void Write<T>(T x) { System.Console.Write("{0}\n", x); }
```

Comment: Because in such situations (may be not in this case) already existing polymorphism: x.ToString() is defined for all relevant types.
I am trying to wrap classes without truly virtual methods (but with properly defined overloads) with classes providing a virtual method .

Answer (score 3):

The C++ and C# generics are different ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b(v=VS.80).aspx , search for "c# c++ generics difference" on your favorite search site)

Short: C# compiler must create complete `GenWriter<T>` class with all type matching by just looking at the class itself. So it does not know if T will only be int/string or any other type.

C++ compiler creates actual class by looking at instantiation of the generic `GenWriter<int>` and declaration `GenWriter<T>` and then creates class for that particular instance.

Answer (score 1):

If someone was to call `GenWriter(5.0)`, this would be inferred to `GenWriter<double>(5.0)`, and the method call inside `Write(T x)` would become:

```
public static void Write(double x) { Poly.WriteVal(x); }
```

There is no overload of `WriteVal` which takes a double. The compiler is informing you that there are no valid overloads of `WriteVal`.

C# generics and C++ templates are not entirely equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in C# because the compiler doesn't know what is the type of x in compile time.

Without knowledge of T's actual type, the compiler is concerned that you might have intended to perform a *custom* conversion. The simplest solution is to use the as operator, which is unamibigous because it cannot perform a custom conversion.

A more gereral solution is to cast to object first. This is helpfull because of boxing unboxing issues:

```
return (int)(object) x;
```

Have in mind that C# Generics are not like C++ templates. C++ templates are pieces of code that compile for each type separately. While C# generics are compiled in an assebmly.