# Generic type class defition

Tags: java, class, templates, generics, variables

There is a nice discussion of [generics here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i)

But they all talk about how the class can accept generic type variable. My question is rather on the generic type class definition.

The class is defined as

```
protected final <T> T getBeanFromSpringContext(String name, Class<T> requiredType) {
    if(springApplicationContext != null) {
        return springApplicationContext.getBean(name, requiredType);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I understand that the return type is `T`. But then `<T>` before that is the type of the class modeled by this Class object. Why is this not `<?>` as I don't know the type?

And since the return type is `T`. Can this class return `null` as is mentioned above?

Comment: btw, I prefer this single-line style: `return springApplicationContext == null ? null : springApplicationContext.getBean(name, requiredType);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *`<T>` before that* is a declaration saying that the method is generic, and it has a type parameter `T`—that is, it's a [definition of a type variable](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108850).

It could be a bit different:

```
protected final <T extends Collection> T getBeanFromSpringContext(String name, Class<T> requiredType) {
    if(springApplicationContext != null) {
        return springApplicationContext.getBean(name, requiredType);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That will not only say that you have a type parameter, but would also put some constraints, "bounds", on its values.

Update: now, on the `null` part. Unfortunately, all the non-primitive types mean "this type or `null`" in Java. So yes, you can always return null. And you can always get an NPE.

[An obligatory Angelika Langer's FAQ link](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html#FAQ001)