# What does <> do in Java

Tags: java

I am currently new to working with Java. So far I have been able to easily use the basic such as `Classes`, `Functions`, `Arrays` etc from my knowledge of JavaScript and PHP.

However, what I have never seen before is this: `<>`. Inside of that is a variable of some type. Because I don't know what it is called, I can't find any answers.

I've seen them like this:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But also like:

```
public static <T> boolean contains( final T[] array, final T v ) {
    for ( final T e : array )
        if ( e == v || v != null && v.equals( e ) )
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

What does the `<String>` mean?
In the function, I was also wondering what is specifically special about the `T`?

Comment: Search "java generic".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891567/what-does-do-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Search something related to this, before post any question

Comment: And why exactly the downvotes? I said I didn't know what it was called.

Comment: I agree with @Shawn31313, there is no reason to downvote here. I mean, you can do it out of freewill but there won't any purpose to it because this adheres to FAQ and it is a genuine question.

Comment: @Shawn31313 happens sometimes, I upvoted. How can we search for something without knowing what it is called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does <> (angle brackets) mean in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-angle-brackets-mean-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for a [Generic type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

What it allows you to do is to pass through a type, and make it useful for multiple object types

So List is a generic collection, and it allows you to make a list of any object. Making `List<String>` will make the object be a list of Strings. Or you could use `List<MyClassType>` and it would make a list of objects of your class

Answer (score 2):

That defines the `Type` of the objects a collection can hold

so when you write `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();`, it means

- Create an arrayList that can hold the String objects.

  SomeParameterizedClass{
     T someValue;
  }

means that you can pass your type to the class e.g. `SomeParameterizedClass<String>` so that `someValue` becomes of type `String`

When you write  `List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();`, here T can be any type.

With java 7 you can simply say `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`. It has the same meaning.

In java 7 `<>` is called as diamond operator

Comment: In the last line do you mean `List<> list = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: No, the last line is correct `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`. There should be something that tell what kind of objects it can take :). This diamond syntax helps less typing without changing meaning.

Comment: But I thought `<>` meant it could hold anything?

Answer (score 0):

You will find < > in the following cases, the T is a "parameter type" in plain English that means you could "substitute" that T by any other non-primitive type (like `String` or `Integer`):

- When you are declaring a parameterized Type:

  ```
  class MyParameterizedClass<T> {

      public T myValue;

  }
  ```
- When you are declaring variables of your parameterized type:

  ```
  MyParameterizedClass<String> myStringParam;
  MyParameterizedClass<Integer> myIntegerParam;
  ```
- When you are using constructors of parameterized types:

  ```
  MyParameterizedClass<String> myStringParam = new MyParameterizedClass<String>();
  MyParameterizedClass<Integer> myIntegerParam = new MyParameterizedClass<Integer>();

  myStringParam.myValue = "Hello world";
  myIntegerParam.myValue = 5;
  ```
- When you declare a generic method:

  ```
  public <T> T updateMyValue(T myValue) {
      this.myValue = myValue
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

What you have observed is partially correct! In Java, inside <> should be 'Object' type or any subclass type of 'Object'.

When you declare myList as below:

`List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>()`, it ensures the declared and initialized myList has elements of only String type. This is called type declarations.

`public static <T> boolean contains( final T[] array, final T v ) { }`, is a generic method declaration which implies that the passed two parameters should be of same object type, 1st parameter an array, 2nd parameter an object. And the method return type also should be same type.

Refer Java docs for more examples on Generics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html