# C# equivalent for java arraylist supporting get, set and remove certain Index

Tags: c#, java, collections, arraylist, linked-list

I am a Java programmer, I have used a Java `ArrayList` before and now I want to have something like that in C#. Some of options I need are in this Java code:

```
String[] strs = new String[]{"str1" , "str2" , "str3" , "str4"};
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(35);
arrayList.add(strs[0]);
arrayList.add(strs[1]);
arrayList.remove(0);
arrayList.set(0, strs[2]);
String s = (String) arrayList.get(1);
```

I used C# `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, but they don't have these simple options that I need. Is there another option in C# supporting accessing objects with indexes, inserting and removing from certain index?

Comment: Use `List<T>`,`List[index]` and [`List.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: wow that's confusing; nowadays it is common to think of a List as a shorthand for a Linked List, rather than a contiguous colection.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use `List <T>`

```
 String[] strs = new String[]{"str1" , "str2" , "str3" , "str4"};
 List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
 stringList.add(strs[0]);
 stringList.add(strs[1]);
 stringList.RemoveAt(indexYouWantToDelete)     
 String s = stringList[0];
```

ArrayLists in c# come from the pre-generic era tho. Since C# 2.0 we have generic collections, `List <T>` being one example of that. As the comment on this answer says, if you use an ArrayList, the elements that you put into the arraylist will have to be boxed (to `Object`, because thats the only thing an ArrayList takes as input). If you want to access them after that, they will have to be explicitly unboxed, like what you did in your question.  ( --> `String s = (String) arrayList.get(1);` )

using generic collections (like `List <T>`), there is no boxing anymore, as the compiler knows what datatype the list will consist of. In this case, Strings.
You could also have a `List<int>`, `List<char>`, or `List<whatever>`, and you can use the same indexing functionality on them.

Comment: it might be worth pointing out that the use of `ArrayList` is *not* recommended as it is non-generic and causes boxing.

Comment: thank you! firstly I thought that LinkedList is more advanced than pure List and I didn't note to that.

Comment: OK... I understood the generic data types are inherited from C and are equivalent to templates in C and C++. But non-generic data types are behaved like objects and need type casting. Thank you!

Comment: Here are the differences between C# and java generics and C templates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31929/284240.

Answer (score 3):

Use `List<T>` ...........................................

which has `Add` `Remove`, `RemoveAt` indexers like `list[i]` etc.