# what is the equivalent of arraylist.get(index) in arraylist C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have to convert some code from Java to C#, and I don't know what the equivalent is of `Arraylist.get(index)` from Java in .NET C#.

I want to convert something like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<M+1;i++)
    if(SF.get(i) == SC.get(i))
        ok= true;
    else ok=false;
```

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342637/c-sharp-equivalent-for-java-arraylist-supporting-get-set-and-remove-certain-ind

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <M +1; i++) {ok = SF[i] == SC[i]; ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < M + 1; i++)
{
    if (SF[i] == SC[i])
        ok = true;

    else
        ok = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the item property provided by the overloaded "[]" operator.
MSDN => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx List.Item Property (Int32)

For example:

```
var value  = SC[index]
```

Comment: The correct term for that `[]` is **indexer** in C# and **Default Property** in VB.NET.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6x16t2tx.aspx