# Disadvantages of generic types in C #

Tags: c#, c++, generics

I have repeatedly heard that generics in C# are less powerful than templates in C++. But I have not heard any arguments in favor of (or against) this. Is it really so, if so, in what it shows?

I recently faced with the strange feature that if `SomeClassChild` is descendant of class `SomeClass`, then `List<SomeClassChild>` can not be converted to `List<SomeClass>`, whereas `SomeClassChild[]` to `SomeClass[]` - can.

The following code will also result in an error:

```
List<SomeClass> lst = new List<SomeClass>();
lst.Add(new SomeClassChild());
```

Comment: You might be interested in reading this: [Array covariance: not just ugly, but slow too - By Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/06/22/array-covariance-not-just-ugly-but-slow-too.aspx). Array covariance is one of the dark corners of C#.

Comment: No, it will not error out. I just tried it, compiles no problem.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw Is of course referring to your last example, of adding a sub-type to a list of supertypes, which works just fine, not the list covariance case, which does indeed not work (nor should it).

Comment: Covariance and contravariance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx ... SO link for generics vs. templates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i

Comment: Also, from Eric Lippert: "this particular kind of covariance is broken. It was added to the CLR because Java requires it and the CLR designers wanted to be able to support Java-like languages." from [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Two: Array Covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)

Comment: Another drawback of [tag:c#] generics I remember you can't do such things as the [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You say drawback, I say benefit ;)

Comment: @Servy There is a vast number of pretty good use cases for CRTP based problem solutions, but that may be opinion based (I'm using [tag:c++] mainly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book "C# in depth", it has a topic on comparing generics between languages. As C++/C#, I just copy some content form the book:

1. The C++ compiler is smart enough to compile the code only once for any given set
   of template arguments, but it isn’t able to share code in the way that the CLR does with
   reference types. That lack of sharing does have its benefits, though—it allows type specific optimizations, such as inlining method calls for some type parameters but not
   others, from the same template. It also means that overload resolution can be performed separately for each set of type parameters, rather than just once based solely
   on the limited knowledge the C# compiler has due to any constraints present.
2. One significant feature that C++ templates have over C# generics is that the template arguments don’t have to be type names. Variable names, function names, and
   constant expressions can be used as well. A common example of this is a buffer type
   that has the size of the buffer as one of the template arguments—a buffer 
   will always be a buffer of 20 integers, and a bufferwill always be a buffer
   of 35 doubles. This ability is crucial to template metaprogramming (see the Wikipedia
   article,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming),  which  is  an
   advanced C++ technique, the very idea of which scares me but that can be powerful in
   the hands of experts.
3. C++ templates are more flexible in other ways too. They don’t suffer from the lack
   of operator constraints and there are a few other restrictions
   that don’t exist in C++: you can derive a class from one of its type parameters, and you
   can specialize a template for a particular set of type arguments. The latter ability allows
   the template author to write general code to be used when there’s no more knowledge
   available, and specific (often highly optimized) code for particular types.

If you want to find out more, check the book.