# Difference between ArrayList<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and ArrayList iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

What is the difference between this two line:

```
ArrayList<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Step 1: raise a compile time error

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    iList.add(10);
    iList.add("Test_Element"); // Compiler error, while trying to insert a String in an Integer ArrayList 
    System.out.print("Value of 2nd element: " + iList.get(1));
 }
```

Step 2: works fine

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    iList.add(10);
    iList.add("Test_Element"); // works fine, while trying to insert a String in an Integer ArrayList 
    System.out.print("Value of 2nd element: " + iList.get(1));
 }
```

Output:
Value of 2nd element: Test_Element

**I am expecting an error like**

"add(java.lang.Integer) in ArrayList cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)", but in step2 two it works fine.

Could anyone please explain me, why I am able to insert a String in this list.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689673/arraylist-generic-without-type

Comment: That is because of [raw types. Don't use them.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/507738)

Comment: You will not get any error, because your second type is Generic. You can add any type of object inside your second ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

There's no compile-time check on generic type of `ArrayList` when you write `ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Integer>()`. The generic type on the right side of the assignment expression is basically ignored. `ArrayList` doesn't *really* have an inner type, just that the `T` in `ArrayList<T>` helps you make sure you only perform operations with instances of `T` on your list.

It would be useful to understand why you want to have integers and strings mixed in the same `ArrayList`--there might be a design smell here :)