# How can JComboBox be created with keyword "new" and without angle brackets?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I'm trying to build some small application (practicing things I have read). I'm using a `JComboBox` components. According to the Java API `JComboBox` requires angle brackets (`<E>`). Surprisingly, using `JComboBox` without `<>` also works. I'm trying to understand how does it work?

I have not learned yet "Generic" (How does it works in background, how to a generic class), only used them.

```
String[] season = {"Winter","Summer","Spring","Fall"};
JComboBox someComboBox = new JComboBox(season);
```

It works while I expected a compilation error, but notifies me that I had to specify an object inside brackets.

Comment: Thats just how generics work, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689673/arraylist-generic-without-type) question. In my opinion, the answer by @Harshad Ranganathan is good.

Comment: "without <> also works" but you get a warning

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt, thanks. great explanation in the attached link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java 7 `JComboBox` is a [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), which means that when declaring a variable of this type you are expected to perform a *generic type invocation* by supplying a *type argument* which represents "the type of the elements of this combo box" [[from the API]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html).

In your case this means:

```
JComboBox<String> someComboBox = new JComboBox<>(season);
```

Interestingly the [Java Tutorial on JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) appears not to have been updated to the generic version of `JComboBox`.

If, for this or any other reason, you wish to use `JComboBox` without doing a generic type invocation, this is still possible because Java supports using [*raw types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

> A raw type is the name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments.

So you can use the `JComboBox` raw type as:

```
JComboBox someComboBox = new JComboBox(season);
```

Although this is not recommended, if you just want to experiment or follow the tutorial, then it should not be a big deal.

If you find the compiler warnings are distracting, you might be able to get rid of them by appropriately setting the compiler error/warning properties in your IDE. Alternatively, you can get rid of them using the [@SuppressWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation. If supported by your compiler, adding the annotation instance to your code should get rid of the warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(season);
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java) for more info on `@SuppressWarnings`.