# Generic Classes term question based on the the data type

Tags: java

I understand with Generic classes in Java the class can have the parameter be almost of any data type. For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrl1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
ArrayList<String> arrl2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here I am making one ArrayList to be of String type and the other to be of Integer type. In this case when referring to the two or separately, should I just treat them both as ArrayList objects or should both be treated as separately like one is an ArrayList object and the other is a String type Array List object. Which way is recommended to do, I do know due to type erasure both in compile time are just ArrayList.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayList Generic without Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689673/arraylist-generic-without-type)

Comment: Avoid raw types. Use List<?> if you don't care about the type of the list. Also, please reformat your question. It it too verbose and difficult to understand in its current form.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *treat*. Generics provide a compile-time safety. If you don't care whether strings or integers are contained in the list, you can just use `ArrayList<?>`.

Comment: "should I just treat them both as ArrayList objects" What do you mean by "treat"? Are you asking how you should mentally think of them?