# Why hasn't Java converted its generics to compile time resolution similar to C#?

Tags: java, architecture

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, however, I was not able to find the answer after searching for a while.

So after all this time Java has had generics be a run time resolution scope instead of a compile time scope like C#/.NET.  I am trying to figure out the reason why the Java community has never updated to switch generics to a compile time resolution.  The performance benefits would be particularly large, especially in embedded devices and Android.  Thanks for any insights!

Thanks for the comments.  I think I am phrasing my question poorly then.  I guess what I mean is why are my generics constantly casting at runtime instead of just replacing the proper type in place at runtime.  So maybe why is type erasure necessary? Would be a better question.

Comment: Performance benefits? Generics are erased at runtime. It's at compile-time that they're any use.

Comment: What do you mean by Java generics being resolved at run time ? Java generic type checks happen at compile-time only.

Comment: See [Java Documentation: Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: Ok after some more searching I eventually found a most that was spot on for answering my question.  I really did ask it poorly, but for anyone trying to understand the same thing here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i