# Vala generics to C code

Tags: c, generics, compiler-construction, vala

I was reading about the language vala and that it compiles to Ansi C code. However I also saw it supports generics like Java or Rust. Now my question is how this is compiled to C code? If I have a gerneric class or function, what kind of C code is generated to simulate the generic behavior?

Comment: Say you write a generic `list<Stuff>` and then use a `list<int>` and a `list<double>`. The Vala compiler will write C-structs `list_int` and `list_double` that have the appropriate behavior. In other words the work of instantiating a specific generic is done by Vala.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the same as C++ templates? But templates haven't the exactly same behavior as generics I think.

Comment: C++ templates behave similarly to C# generics (as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31929/69809)). It's the same way vala generics will create actual structs for each generic parameter you pass.

Comment: C++ templates are not compiled into C-code, but the concept is the same. Of course the C-structs are written in a way to have the behavior that is correct according to Vala specs, not what C++ or C# say.

Comment: @nwp Only one C struct is created, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vala generics are based on `gpointer` and `GType`.

You can only specialize a Generic class with a pointer based type parameter.

```
class MyClass<T> {

public T val;

}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    // This wouldn't compile!
    // var il = new Gee.ArrayList<int> ();

    var il = new Gee.ArrayList<int?> ();
    var dl = new Gee.ArrayList<double?> ();
    il.add (5);
    dl.add (3.0);

    var im = new MyClass<int?>();
    im.val = 5;

    var dm = new MyClass<double?>();
    dm.val = 3.0;

    var lm = new MyClass< Gee.List<int?> > ();
    lm.val = il;

    return 0;
}
```

You can check the generated code yourself with the `-C` parameter:

```
valac -C Main.vala --pkg gee-0.8
```

This will generate a `main.c` file. If you read it carefully you will see there is only one struct for MyClass (plus some additional helper structs that are needed for GObject based classes) that has a member `gpointer val`, it also has a `GType t_type` as well as a `t_dup_func` and a `t_destroy_func`.

```
struct _MyClass {
        // ...
        gpointer val;
};

struct _MyClassPrivate {
        GType t_type;
        GBoxedCopyFunc t_dup_func;
        GDestroyNotify t_destroy_func;
};
```

To ensure the correct type is passed in [GLib type checking](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html) is performed. This makes Vala generics type safe (partially at compile time and partially at runtime).

This is in contrast with C++ templates which are expanded at compile time. So it is closer to C# generics than to classic C++ templates.

I wrote "partially at compile time" because the Vala compiler is smart enough to omit the type check in the C code when it knows that the assignment will always be correct.

Also Vala generated C code is meant to be easily consumable for other programming languages that have GLib bindings (like C, Python, C++, GJS, etc.)