# C# specialize generic class

Tags: c#, generics, template-specialization

Is it possible to do the following specialization in C#? I can do this in C++ but do not understand how to achieve the same result in C#.

```
class GenericPrinter<T>
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unspecialized method");
    }
}

class GenericPrinter<int>
{
    public void Print()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Specialized with int");
    }
}
```

Added:

The problem with suggested `GenericPrinterInt` solution is that I need to explicitly create it. `new GenericPrinter<int>` will still print `Unspecialized method`.

What I want is to use this GenericPrinter from another generic class without the knoledge is T equal to int or something else.

Comment: C++ templates are not .NET generics. You can't.

Comment: Here is a very good reading explaining even the differences for the Java generics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i .

Comment: You can't. You'll need to find some other way to deal with the situation.

Comment: you can however make your Print function generic 'public void Print<T>()'

Comment: @Nosturion Please see my updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40470730/2878550).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess the closer you could get in C# would be:

```
class GenericPrinter<T>
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unspecialized method");
    }
}

class IntPrinter : GenericPrinter<int>
{
    public override void Print()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Specialized with int");
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the answer is, you can't specialize in C#.

As Lyubomyr Shaydariv said in his comment:

> C++ templates are not .NET generics. You can't.

---

From your edit I guess you will have some type checking to make.

You can do this with a dictionary for example.

```
class GenericPrinter<T>
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action> _actions
        = new Dictionary<Type, Action>()
    {
        { typeof(int), PrintInt }
    };

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        foreach (var pair in _actions)
            if (pair.First == typeof(T))
            {
                pair.Second();
                return ;
            }
        Console.WriteLine("Unspecialized method");
    }

    public virtual void PrintInt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specialized with int");
    }
}
```

Like you can see, you will have to make a method for each type, you want to handle. And you may also encounter some issues when you will try to manipulate T as int. Since, `T` is really generic (it hasn't any constraint), it will more likely act as an `object` in your code (not at runtime) you will have to cast it like that `(int)(object)yourTVariable` in your methods **where you are sure that `T` is an `int`**.

But for this part, I guess some of my peers, will have a better answer than me to give to you.

---

If it's just about displaying which type you are using:

```
public virtual void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Specialized with {typeof(T).Name}");
}
```

But you won't have the unspecialized message anymore (and if you think about it, you can't have a GenericPrinter instantiated without specifying its type. Then it makes no sense to have a method that displays "unspecialized", **you will always have a specified type**)

Anyway, the answer is still the same, **you can't specialize a generic in C#**.

Comment: Voteup for the speed. You were 1 minute faster. ;)

Comment: @Dmitry: (Even if the rules forbid this kind of comment) Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

It isn't possible in C#.
You can use inheritance instead:

```
class GenericPrinter<T>
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unspecialized method");
    }
}

class GenericPrinterInt : GenericPrinter<int>
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specialized with int");
    }
}
```

---

According to the updated question, I can only suggest you the following approach. You could create a static factory method in which you can check the type of `T` and instantiate an appropriate specialized class if the type matches the criteria:

```
class GenericPrinter<T>
{
    public static GenericPrinter<T> Create()
    {
        if (typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            return (GenericPrinter<T>)(object)new GenericPrinterInt();

        if (typeof(double).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            return (GenericPrinter<T>)(object)new GenericPrinterDouble();

        // Other types to check ...

        return new GenericPrinter<T>();
    }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unspecialized method");
    }
}

class GenericPrinterInt : GenericPrinter<int>
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specialized with int");
    }
}

class GenericPrinterDouble : GenericPrinter<double>
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specialized with double");
    }
}
```

Some other generic class:

```
class SomeGenericClass<T>
{
    public readonly GenericPrinter<T> Printer = GenericPrinter<T>.Create();
}
```

Usage sample:

```
var intClass = new SomeGenericClass<int>();
intClass.Printer.Print();
// Output: Specialized with int

var doubleClass = new SomeGenericClass<double>();
doubleClass.Printer.Print();
// Output: Specialized with double

var stringClass = new SomeGenericClass<string>();
stringClass.Printer.Print();
// Output: Unspecialized method
```

Comment: With one minute between us, we have exactly the same answer x)

Comment: Well, since the OP edited his post, you can make something different than me, regarless of the speed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you need to move your code into lambda expressions
or some flavor of lambdas.
It's not pretty but is fast ( no lookups ) and has the specialization.
You can tailor this to your needs

Cummon Microsoft we shouldn't have to do this.
How many improvements to .Net and no specialization.

```
public class GenericPrinter<T>
{
    public static GenericPrint()
    {
       T thing = default(T)
       switch(thing)
       {
       case int ival:
          _Print = ()=>
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Specialized Int print Code");
              };
            break;
        default:
          _Print = ()=>
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Some generic print code");
            };
            break;

       }
   }

   // will be unique for every type of T
   public static Action _Print=null;
 
   public void Print()
   { 
       _Print();
   }

}
```

Use would be the same

```
var printer = new GenericPrinter<int>();
printer.Print();
```