# Why can't an implementation of an interface's method return a generic parameter type that has the correct constraints applied? (C#)

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

Given the following code:

```
public interface IFoo {}

public interface IBar
{
    IFoo MyMethod();
}   

public abstract class MyClass<T> : IBar where T : IFoo
{
    public abstract T MyMethod();
}
```

Why am I receiving the error `MyClass<T> does not implement interface member IBar.MyMethod(). MyClass<T>.MyMethod() cannot implement IBar.MyMethod() because it does not have the matching return type of IFoo.`?

I added the constraint `where T : IFoo`, so I would have expected T and IFoo to be interchangeable.

Comment: Because the two signatures have nothing to do with each other. Even without generics you wouldn't be able to use `public MyFoo MyMethod()` as the implementation of `IFoo MyMethod();`. Moreover, one method is generic, the other is not. Generics in .NET aren't syntactic sugar, nor are they erased during compilation, they're part of the final IL.

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place, especially when `MyClass` is abstract? What's the *actual* problem you want to solve? It's quite possible there's a different solution already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The signatures are of course different, but I guess I would have assumed the compiler would see the constraint and realize I'm only narrowing the interface method's return type, which isn't breaking any contract (it's just making it more specific)

Comment: @PanagiotosKanavos I also figure there's a better solution but I know SO prefers specific questions so I'm tackling it one bit at a time. The larger architecture question is a bit bigger. This was one approach I took

Comment: That's not a specific question, it's a generalization of the real problem. One based on a couple of wrong assumptions 1) that specialization is allowed (it's not) and 2) that type constraints specify an inheritance relation or they can introduce the non-existent speciaization (they don't). Think about this from the caller's point of view. If I give you an IBar interface that says `MyMethod` returns an `IFoo`, wouldn't you always expect that method to return an `IFoo` ?

Comment: It was a simplified version of the real problem, but it was indeed a very specific question. Perhaps I will make a post with an open-ended "how tf do I do this". Just thought people didn't like that ‍♂️

Comment: "Wouldn't you expect that method to return an IFoo". Yes, but T is an IFoo... That's where I'm confused I guess

Comment: The expectation is wrong then. Interfaces are similar to actual physical interfaces like audio or Ethernet jacks. They're expected to always have the same shape/behavior, no matter who implements them. That's why they don't specify an inheritance relation either. That's what makes them different from abstract classes.

Comment: The question's code is invalid. There are lots  duplicate questions, like [How to do template specialization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600978/how-to-do-template-specialization-in-c-sharp), [C# specialize generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470669/c-sharp-specialize-generic-class), [Why is specialization in C# generics limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305029/why-is-specialization-in-c-sharp-generics-limited), [Template specialization via extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483731/template-specialization-via-extension-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the [C# specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v9/standard/interfaces.md#1865-interface-mapping) states that:

> For purposes of interface mapping, a class or struct member `A` matches
> an interface member `B` when:
>
> - `A` and `B` are methods, and the name, type, and formal parameter lists of `A` and `B` are identical.

So the return types must be identical.

The feature of allowing covariant returns of interface implementations was proposed once: [The proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns#implicit-interface-implementations).  It is also mentioned that this change will cause the code not to be forward compatible, therefore it may be declined, and finally it was really [declined](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2020/LDM-2020-01-08.md#covariant-returns).

> Due to this breaking change, we might consider not supporting covariant return types on implicit implementations.

Comment: All answers were helpful, but I feel this one was the best. I guess all I needed to hear was "yes this could be a feature, but it simply isn't part of the specification"

Answer (score 2):

When implementing a interface you need to use specified return type, just returning a object derived from the correct type is not enough. The following non generic code also fails, for the same reason:

```
public class MyFoo : IFoo { }
public class MyClass : IBar
{
    public MyFoo MyMethod() => new ();
}
```

The reason this does not work seem to simply be that the language designers have not considered the effort worth the cost. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996843/12342238) should explain more and be fairly authoritative on the subject.

The solution is to make an explicit interface implementation that forwards the call to the abstract method:

```
    public abstract class MyClass<T> : IBar where T : IFoo
    {
        public abstract T MyMethod();
        IFoo IBar.MyMethod() => MyMethod();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have two implementations of `IFoo`:

```
public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public int SomeOtherMethod() => 42;
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo {}
```

Notice that `Foo1` defines an extra member, while `Foo2` does not.

Furthermore, *imagine* that .NET generics work a bit more like C++ templates - not that I really know how those work, either, but imagine that at compile-time we replace the generics with their actual types.

We might imagine that the result is two copies of `MyClass<T>`:

```
public abstract class MyClass<Foo1> : IBar
{
    public abstract Foo1 MyMethod();
}

public abstract class MyClass<Foo2> : IBar
{
    public abstract Foo2 MyMethod();
}
```

First of all, technically, none of those classes implement `IBar` because they don't have the right return type from `MyMethod()`.

Second, this might enable you to write client code like this:

```
var mc = new MyClass<Foo1>();
var foo = mc.MyMethod(); // foo is Foo1
var i = foo.SomeOtherMethod();
```

This, on the other hand, wouldn't work if you changed `Foo1` to `Foo2`, since the third line wouldn't compile, as `Foo2` has no `SomeOtherMethod` member.

Why doesn't this work? The short (and perhaps somewhat unsatisfactory) answer is that this is not how .NET generics work. .NET doesn't have higher-kinded types or return-type polymorphism.

This isn't, however, an inconceivable language feature. Haskell has higher-kinded types, and would be able to do what you ask about (I'm fairly sure, but to be honest, I haven't though deeply about how the equivalent code might look). .NET, however, doesn't currently allow this.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response, it definitely helped me make sense of it