# Create a c++ vector with one data type but different templates

Tags: java, c++

I'm relatively new to C++ and have previously only programmed in Java. Now I want to switch and write a few programs in C++ for exercise.

In doing so, I came across a problem that I couldn't solve even after a long search: I want to create a vector with a fixed object. This object already exists and needs a template data type for creation, for example a string or an int.

Now comes the problem: I want to create objects of this data type with a method, pass the template to the method and then add the whole thing to a vector. The whole thing always returns the following error:

Error: invalid use of incomplete type

To make the problem more understandable for you, I wrote my plan in Java: You can find the files here:

Main.java:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestObjectManagement testObjectManagement = new TestObjectManagement();
        testObjectManagement.add(new TestObject<String>("test", "test"));
        testObjectManagement.add(new TestObject<Integer>(4, "test"));
        
        for(int i = 0; i<testObjectManagement.testarraylist.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("For the name " + testObjectManagement.testarraylist.get(i).getName() + " is the value " + testObjectManagement.testarraylist.get(i).getContentType() + " saved!");
        }
    }

}
```

TestObjectManagement.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestObjectManagement {
public ArrayList<TestObject<?>> testarraylist;
    public TestObjectManagement() {
        testarraylist = new ArrayList<TestObject<?>>();
    }
    public void add(TestObject<?> testobject) {
        testarraylist.add(testobject);
    }
    
}
```

TestObject.java

```
public class TestObject<ContentType> {
String name;
ContentType t;
    public TestObject(ContentType t, String name) {
        this.t = t;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public ContentType getContentType() {
        return t;
    }

}
```

If something is unclear, please ask, but I think the source code should be easy to understand.

Many thanks for the help.
Here is my C++ code: Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestObjectManagement.h"

int main()
{  
    TestObjectManagement* test = new TestObjectManagement();
    test->addTestObject(TestObject<int>(3));
}
```

TestObjectManagement.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "TestObject.h"
class TestObjectManagement
{
public:
    TestObjectManagement();
    void addTestObject(TestObject<class T>);
private:
    std::vector<TestObject<class T>>* testVector;
};
```

TestObjectManagement.cpp

```
#include "TestObjectManagement.h"

TestObjectManagement::TestObjectManagement()
{
    testVector = new std::vector<TestObject<class T>>;
}

void TestObjectManagement::addTestObject(TestObject<class T> testObeject)
{
    testVector->push_back(testObeject);
}
```

TestObject.h

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class TestObject
{
    public:
    TestObject(T value);
    private:
        T value;
};

template<class T>
TestObject<T>::TestObject(T value)
{
    TestObject<T>::value = value;
}
```

Comment: Please post your C++.  We can't tell if it's a one-line error (or typo) or a major misunderstanding.  Also read how to post a [mcve] for the C++ code.

Comment: @RichardCritten he's just new to C++ and asks how to implement Generics in this language

Comment: okay, thank you, I will do.

Comment: @IQbrod OP gets an error from C++: `Error: invalid use of incomplete type` so I think it's useful to see what he has done so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Generics in C# and Java... and Templates in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing will be a problem to think about, like its last sentence, *For example, inserting an object into a standard library collection (such as a std::vector) actually involves making and inserting a copy into the collection.*

Comment: I tried to use std::any, but Visual Studio shows me that std doesn't contain any. What can be the reason?

Comment: You say “with one data type” but then (in Java) show it containing a `TestObject<String>` and a `TestObject<Integer>`, whose obvious translations into C++ would be *different* types precisely because of their different template arguments.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found a solution.